# Exception in Application init method

Tags: java, exception, javafx, log4j, gtk

After upgrading to the latest Java JDK (8) I get this Error after running it in Eclipse:

```
Exception in Application init method
```

And after exporting it into a .jar file I get this:

```
    Exception in thread "main" Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:383)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
    ... 5 more
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Layout
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplicationWithArgs$156(LauncherImpl.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$49(GtkApplication.java:139)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Layout
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 11 more
```

What can I do to prevent this error?

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Layout`. Updated something else too have we?

Comment: @BoristheSpider No. Only the JDK.

Comment: Didn't you ask this [yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38961148/exception-in-init-method-javafx)? Your classpath is wrong.

Comment: @James_D Well, if I set it: set classpath=~/Desktop/memo.jar;~/Desktop/jfxrt.jar
/home/me/Desktop/jfxrt.jar: line 1: $'PK\003\004': command not found
/home/me/Desktop/jfxrt.jar: line 2: $'\334v:E': command not found
/home/me/Desktop/jfxrt.jar: line 3: �v:Ec��jjMETA-INF/MANIFEST.MFManifest-Version:: No such file or directory
/home/me/Desktop/jfxrt.jar: line 4: Ant-Version:: command not found
/home/me/Desktop/jfxrt.jar: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/home/me/Desktop/jfxrt.jar: line 5: `Created-By: 1.6.0_51-b11 (Sun Microsys'ems Inc.)

Comment: Yes, because that is not valid syntax for setting the classpath. Even if it were, you'd be pointing it to two different jfxrt.jar files, and with Java 8 you don't need *any* as jfxrt.jar is in the bootstrap classpath. Besides which, the problem isn't that JavaFX is missing, the problem is that your Apache logging library is missing.

Comment: @James_D Oh. I just added this: log4j-1.2.17.jar. It still gives me this error. Which .jar file do I need to add until it works?

Comment: No one can really tell you what jar files you have downloaded onto your system and what their contents are. FWIW I have a jar file called log4j-1.2.17.jar, which does indeed contain org.apache.log4j.Layout. So either you have a file of the same name with different content, or you haven't actually set the classpath correctly (I can't even tell what OS you are using...), or you're not really getting the same error.

Comment: @James_D I am using Ubuntu 16.04. I used this command to set the classpath: set classpath=~/Desktop/memo.jar:~/Desktop/log4j-1.2.17.jar. While both files are saved on the desktop.

Comment: So do `jar tf ~/Desktop/log4j-1.2.17.jar | grep -f Layout` and see if the jar file really contains that class. I don't know Ubuntu and what shell you are in, so you may need to export the classpath. Or just use the -cp option to java directly. What JDK are you using btw? "Java 8 includes JavaFX" only applies to Oracle JDKs.

Comment: @James_D I am using jdk1.8.0_101 - downloaded from the oracle website. grep returns: grep: Layout: No such file or directory

Comment: Uh, you must have a version of grep that I'm not familiar with. Pipe the jar command through `more` instead and just manually look for the class

Comment: Oh, actually, just omit the `-f` in the previous command.

Comment: @James_D This is the output: jar tf ~/Desktop/log4j-1.2.‌​17.jar | grep Layout
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/bostrot/Desktop/log4j-1.2.‌​17.jar (No such file or directory)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
 at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:120)
 at sun.tools.jar.Main.list(Main.java:1115)
 at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:293)
 at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:1288)

Comment: So the problem is that when you set the classpath, you are pointing to a jar file that doesn't exist....

Comment: @James_D Sorry. I just copy & pasted the command. Here is my output: org/apache/log4j/EnhancedPatternLayout.class
org/apache/log4j/HTMLLayout.class
org/apache/log4j/Layout.class
org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.class
org/apache/log4j/SimpleLayout.class
org/apache/log4j/TTCCLayout.class
org/apache/log4j/helpers/DateLayout.class
org/apache/log4j/jmx/LayoutDynamicMBean.class
org/apache/log4j/xml/XMLLayout.class

Comment: @James_D any suggestions?